# Building composable directed graphs (Thompson's construction algorithm for scanner generator)

Tags: c++, graph, compiler-construction, lexer, directed-graph

I am currently writing a scanner generator based on [Thompson's construction algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thompson%27s_construction) to turn regular expressions into NFAs. Basically, I need to parse an expression and create a directed graph from it. I usually store my diGraphs as adjacency lists, but this time, I need to be able to combine existing diGraphs into a new diGraph very efficiently. I can't afford to copy my adjacency lists every time I read a new character.

I was considering creating a very lightweight NFA struct, that wouldn't own its own nodes/states.

```
struct Transition {
  State* next_state;
  char transition_symbol;
};

struct State {
  std::vector<Transition> transitions;
};

struct NFA {
  State* start_state;
  State* accepting_state;
};
```

That would allow me to simply reassign pointers to create new NFAs. All my states would be stored in a central location (NFABuilder?). The composition would be done through external functions like so:

```
NFA create_trivial_nfa(char symbol) {
  State* start_state = new State();
  State* accepting_state = new State();
  start_state->transitions.emplace_back(accepting_state, symbol);
  // Something must own start_state and accepting_state
  return NFA{start_state, accepting_state};
}

NFA concatenate_nfas(NFA&& nfa0, NFA&& nfa1) {
  nfa0.accepting_state->transitions.emplace_back(nfa1.start_state, '\0');
  return NFA{nfa0.start_state, nfa1.accepting_state};
}
```

Here, I would use move semantics to make it clear that nfa0 and nfa1 are not longer to be used as standalone NFAs (since I modified their internal states).

Does this approach make sense, or is there a problem I have not yet anticipated? If it does make sense, what should be the owner of all these states? I am also anticipating a padding issue with my transitions. When packed in a vector, a Transition will have a size of 16 bytes instead of 9 (on a 64bit architecture). Is this something I should worry about or is it just noise in the grand scheme of things? (this is my first compiler. I am following [Engineering a Compiler, by Cooper & Torczon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/012088478X))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The essence of Thompson's construction is that it creates an NFA with the following characteristics:

1. There are at most `2|R|` states, where `|R|` is the length of the regex.
2. Every state has either exactly one out transition labeled with a character or at most two ε transitions. (That is, no state has both a labeled transition and an ε transition.)

The latter fact suggests that representing a state as

```
struct State {
  std::vector<std::tuple<char, State*>> transitions;
}
```

(which is a slight abbreviation of your code) is a very high overhead representation, where the overhead has a lot more to do with the overhead of the `std::vector` used to hold exactly one or two transitions than the padding of a single transition. Moreover, the above representation does not provide a clear technique for representing ε transitions, unless the intention was to reserve one character code for ε (and thereby make it impossible to use that character code in a regular expression).

A more practical representation might be

```
enum class StateType { EPSILON, IMPORTANT };
struct State {
  StateType type;
  char      label;
  State*    next[2];
};
```

(That formulation doesn't store the number of transitions in `next`, on the assumption that we can use a sentinel value to indicate that `next[1]` doesn't apply. Alternatively, we could just set `next[1] = next[0];` in such a case. Remember that it only matters for ε states.)

Moreover, since we know there are no more than `2|R|` `State` objects in the NFA, we could replace the `State*` pointers with small integers. That will set some sort of limit on the size of a regular expression which could be handled, but it's pretty uncommon to encounter gigabyte regexes. Using consecutive integers rather than pointers will also make certain graph algorithms more manageable, in particular the transitive closure algorithm which is fundamental to the subset construction.

Another interesting fact about the NFA constructed by the Thompson algorithm is that the in-degree of States is also limited to 2 (and again, if there are two in-transitions, both will be ε transitions). This allows us to avoid prematurely creating the sub-machines' final states (which will not be needed if the sub-machine is the left-hand argument to concatenation). Instead, we can represent the sub-machine with just three indices: the index of the start state, and the indices of the at most two internal states which will have transitions to the final state once it is added.

I think the above is reasonably close to Thompson's original implementation, although I'm sure he used a lot more optimisation tricks. But it's worth reading Section 3.9 of Aho, Lam, Sethi & Ullman (the "Dragon Book"), which describes ways of optimising construction of state machines.

Independent to the theoretical reductions, it's worth noting that aside from the trie of keyword patterns, the majority of state transitions in lexical analysis involve character sets rather than individual characters, and often these sets are quite large, particularly if the unit of lexical analysis is a Unicode codepoint rather than an ascii character. Using character sets instead of characters does complicate the subset construction algorithm, but it will normally dramatically reduce the state count.

Comment: Very interesting, thank you for the inputs. I will take a look at the dragon book. Also, you directly added the transition symbol to the nodes, and didn't worry about edges at all. Would it make sense to just have an EpsilonState and ImportantState derive from an abstract State? vtable pointers will increase the object size, but the code might end up cleaner?

Comment: @Touloudou: Since "all" of the state's transitions have the same edge label, it's not ok to store it with the state. "IMPORTANT" comes directly from the Dragon Book, by the way; the other states are eliminated by epsilon closure so that the subset construction uses subsets of the important states rather than subsets of all states. This considerably cuts down the number of distinct subsets, so it's well worth doing. Epsilon closure can be computed on the NFA as a whole using a transitive closure algorithm; different State objects don't really help. Just use state numbers.

Comment: However, the "direct to DFA" algorithm described at some length in section 3.9 of the Dragon Book is IMHO a far superior algorithm, particularly if you're writing it in a language with data structures (although I've done it in C, it's not hard).

Comment: Any idea why this approach is not mentioned in the book "Engineering a Compiler", by Cooper & Torczon? Most people online seem to agree that the dragon book is a reference. However, I've also heard many times that some of its content is starting to show its age. C&T is pretty recent and seems to recommend Thompson + subset + Hopcroft and then direct coded scanner (for lexer generators). What's your take on this?

Comment: @Touloudou: I'm definitely not a fan of C&T. I agree that the Dragon Book is showing its age, but it's still a good overview of basic techniques. Frankly, one of the things I would fo differently is skip over all the venerable history of parsing techniques in order to jump directly into the interesting stuff: code generation, static analysis, optimisation, etc. Parsing techniques are a distracting rabbit hole, and I can testify to that as a resident :-) If you want to make a contribution to compiler writing, just use a parser generator to build an AST, and start generating good code.

Comment: The book which taught me the most about the fundamentals is SICP, which predates the Dragon book by several years. Just sayin'.

Comment: Also, I see that C&T issued a new version of their book. Perhaps it's a significant improvement on the first edition; I was never motivated to buy it so I don't know.